# How to convert and add a String to List<byte>?

Tags: c#, string, list, byte

I have a string which I want to convert into bytes (using the encoding.getbytes() function properly) and then the bytes that result from the conversion, add them to a List.

How can I do this? I've thought about doing a for and converting each character in the string and add it one by one to the list but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: As you want to create a List<byte> from 1 string, or a combination of multiple strings?

Comment: psubsee2003: The list already has a few thousand bytes present. There are several strings that I want to convert to bytes and add them in order to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is unnecessary, you can just get the byte array from the string and then call the `AddRange()` method of List to add them to the list.

```
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();  

foreach (var currentString in stringCollection)
{                
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentString);
    byteList.AddRange(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "Kiran Bheemarti";

        List<byte> bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str).ToList();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just convert the GetBytes array to a list?

```
List<byte> byteList = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputString).ToList();
```

Or pass the array to List's constructor:

```
List<byte> byteList = new List<Byte>(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
```

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>' to 'byte'

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of a string with bytes format, you can apply this.

```
var stringByte = new List<string>();

var sr = stringByte.ConvertAll(c => Encoding.Default.GetBytes(c))).ToList();
```